# google oauth2 get token from one-time code using javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax, post, google-signin

I have the one-time code of the sign in user and I want to get his token and refresh token.
I'm using this:

```
            httpReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
            httpReq.open("POST","https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token",true);
            httpReq.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            httpReq.send(dataString);
            console.log(httpReq.responseText);
```

But I get `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 401 (Unauthorized)`

This is `dataString`:

```
"code="+authResult['code']+"&"
 +"client_id="+clientID+"&" +
 "client_secret=<mysecret_client>&" +
 "redirect_uri=&" +
 "grant_type=authorization_code&" +
 "access_type=offline";
```

Comment: Try this URL instead: `https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token`. If that doesn't work, try explicitly url-encoding your data: `httpReq.send(encodeURIComponent(dataString));`

Comment: Ok, changed it. Now I get `XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:63342' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 400.`